# Is it a leak in NSAppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, applescript, memory-leaks

i checked memory many times via 'leak', and found there always existed a leak. could you help me out?

Code here:

```
NSAppleScript* startFinder = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                                  @"tell application \"Finder\"\n"
                                  @"    delay 1\n"
                                  @"    try\n"
                                  @"        «event GKKJload»\n"
                                  @"    on error msg number num\n"
                                  @"        display dialog \"another try\"  buttons{\"i see\"} default button 1 with icon caution  with title \"aaa\"\n"
                                  @"    end try\n"
                                  @"end tell"];
[startFinder executeAndReturnError:nil];
[startFinder release];
```

Thanks in advance for anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that I do.  I've developed a model-view-controller for editing, compiling, and running scripts.

In a case like yours, you would only use the model.  In  my ScriptModel class, it's another layer of abstraction, but it is good I think.  I could change the calls to all of my AppleScripts by changing the ScriptModel implementation to either be NSAppleScript or OSAScript.

```
- (IBAction)test01:(id)sender
{
    ScriptModel* startFinder = [[ScriptModel alloc] initWithSource:
                                  @"tell application \"Finder\"\n"
                                  @"    delay 1\n"
                                  @"    try\n"
                                  @"        «event GKKJload»\n"
                                  @"    on error msg number num\n"
                                  @"        display dialog \"another try\"  buttons{\"i see\"} default button 1 with icon caution with title \"aaa\"\n"
                                  @"    end try\n"
                                  @"end tell"];
    ScriptResult *scriptResult = [startFinder run];
}
```

I'm using ARC, so I believe that my code would work OK.  I can't call the release method in ARC.

Another option for you to consider is to use neither NSAppleScript not OSAScript and not use AppleScript source at all, but just to use Objective-C calls instead using Scripting Bridge:

```
/*

Scripting Bridge for Objective-C
http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html

Although the Objective-C language has existing mechanisms for sending Apple Events, the new Scripting Bridge architecture greatly simplifies the coding necessary to query and control scriptable applications.
*/

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ScriptingBridge/ScriptingBridge.h>
#import "iTunes.h"

int main()
{
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];

NSLog(iTunes.currentTrack.name);
}
```

I think that running AppleScripts from within Objective-C only makes sense if you want to open the scripts up to the user to customize the app.  I'm thinking about using Scripting Bridge for everything else, rather than embedding AppleScripts in my Objective-C code.

Comment: Scripting Bridge doesn't always work right though: it's missing features and is prone to compatibility problems with applications that work fine from AppleScript. A good alternative is the AppleScript-ObjC bridge, which lets you write AppleScript script objects that you can then instantiate and use from your ObjC code just like any other Cocoa object. It has a few limitations and Apple's own documentation is minimal (Shane Stanley's [written a book](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps) on it though), but it's much less hassle than NSAppleScript and much less glitchy than SB.

Comment: Appreciate very much. This is helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

`NSAppleScript` is notorious for leaking memory. Import the `OSAKit` framework and use `OSAScript` in place of `NSAppleScript` (the rest of the code can stay the same).

Comment: I have tried OSAScript. But the leak still exists. Tks all the same.

Comment: @Hize, there is "osascript" (all lower-case) which is a command-line tool.  What about using that?

Comment: @Kaydell
I have never used that before. How should I do it in my code?

Comment: There must be something to do with the source. When I execute several other scripts with different sources, no leak is caused.

Comment: @Hize, here is a link to a proof-of-concept that you can call the command-line tool osascript from Cocoa to evaluate AppleScripts.  It seems kind of "round-about", but it is an idea: https://gist.github.com/kaydell/6189741

Comment: @Kaydell. Got it. Appreciated for your help.